# How come pressing a certain key on the keyboard when working in a webpage changed my input editor's setting?

Tags: keyboard, website, web

I'm translating English subtitles to Chinese for a client and I'm doing it directly on a webpage of the client's website using Firefox. According to the client's specification, when done with translating a subtitle, I can press the Tab key to jump to the next subtitle. Now the weird thing is, after I press Tab, my input method editor (for typing Chinese) will automatically change from Chinese mode to English mode. It's weird because normally the only way to switch the mode of any input method editor for typing Chinese is through pressing the Shift key on the keyboard. Do you have any idea why this happens? What can I do to stop my client's webpage from changing the mode of my input method editor? I just want the input editor to stay in the Chinese mode all the time, despite my pressing the Tab key.

To make sure the problem is not with a particular input editor I use, I also tried two other input editors. The result is the same. :(

The default mode of my input editor has always been Chinese.

My OS is Windows 10.